# Material UI table doesn't work with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

Material UI table structure is as follows

```js
<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>Column 1</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Column 2</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Column 3</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead> 
  
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Cell 3</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

I would like to make the first row of the table a form with inputs. When a submit button is clicked, the new row populates the table.

But when I introduce the form tag, the row disappear from the table.

```js
<TableBody>
  <TableRow>
    <form> 
      <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Cell 3</TableCell>
    </form>
  </TableRow>
</TableBody>
```

Is there any way I can make the MUI table row a form so that when I click submit, I can get the form data object of the row?